# HTML: Garbled text(Extended Ascii characters) appearing intermittently on the IE11 webpage

Tags: html, css, fonts

we are getting a strange problem in IE11 page. while loading the page some of the text looks garbled(showing Extended Ascii characters) and the other part of the text looks fine in the page. When I inspect the element in the DOM, plain original text is there but in webpage it is redenering garbled text. If I modify the text in the DOM, changes are reflecting in the webpage but looks still garbled. When I copy that garbled text on the webpage and paste it on the notepad then it is showing plain original text.
currently using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in the header
When I reboot the machine its showing properly but again it is coming.

Comment: Does this happen on all sites? I.E. is this an IE problem? Otherwise, can you point to a webpage where this happens?

Comment: no only particular site.  To rule out the cause if there is any interference of webserver, we saved that web page alone and just we reloaded the page still we are able to see that garbled text.Again we loaded that same static html page in another machine and its loading with plain English text